# Is it possible to assign a code block to a switch case twice in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, switch-statement

I have some Javascript that is processing a form to send the results to the server through Ajax, and I want to reuse from code to process common components of certain question types. Let's say I have two question types "Forced Choice" and "Forced Choice with Other", both of which use radio buttons to force the user to choose one option, but in the second type, a radio button labeled "other" will allow them to input their own answer into a question box. Getting the radio button value will be common between the two but getting the "other" value will not. Would it be acceptable to say

```
switch(questionType) {
    case 'Forced Choice':
    case 'Forced Choice with Other':
        //code to get radio button value
    case 'Forced Choice with Other':
        //if value was "other", get the value of the textbox
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

or would it be preferable to say

```
switch(questionType) {
    case 'Forced Choice':
    case 'Forced Choice with Other':
        //code to get radio button value
        if(val == 'other' && questionType == 'Forced Choice with Other')
            //code to get "other" value
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Edit: I just wanted to add some clarification that in my actual code, the question type distinction is not as simple as with or without allowing "other". I'd like to use the same code to get the value of all radio-button based questions, and there are several types. For some, it would be as simple as getting the values, but for others, my script would have to check how to script is configured in the form's JSON configuration file. I'd like to use the first pattern to avoid a chunk of several if statements that all have 2-3 conditions.

Which pattern do you think is preferable and why (if the first pattern would even function correctly)?

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, like in a lot of common languages, switch cases "fall through" to the next one unless broken explicitly with a `break` statement. This means that your first example would work, technically, but it's terrible practice, very confusing to read and to maintain *(also, I wouldn't be surprised if the duplicate label confused some interpreters or code analyzers)*.

It's probably best to just extract the common functionality into named functions. This would make your code the easiest to read and maintain, and the repetition would be reduced to calling the same function twice.

Comment: The common code itself it actually just one line, what I'm hoping to avoid is nested trees of if-else statements to deal with other conditions. But as I'm looking at the code now, I'm realizing even if I used the case fall through, I would still need more conditional checking, so I might as well just have it all in one place.

Comment: It might be one line now, but once you start repeating or extending it further, you'll thank yourself for extracting it into a named routine. But it's mostly still OK if you just repeat that one line - what's not OK is a confusing switch structure. But questions about coding style should probably be moved to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think for now I'll go with just that one line, because this is currently a very specific one-time-use project that's only going to be used for a brief period of time. After it's over, I'm going to essentially rewrite the code-base from scratch to make it reusable for future projects... the code in this project is some of the worst I've ever written, because there's been no time for planning. :(

Comment: Do note the question as currently stated would be closed instantly as [off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on Code Review, since it's example code. More on-topic: "fall through" is indeed often frowned upon (exceptions are known). However, multiple if statements after the switch choices are just as bad and should be moved to functions.

Comment: @Mast, indeed, I meant any *further* discussion on style should be moved there, not this question per se.